# What does _() means?

Tags: c#, syntax

In [MoreLinq project's source](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/a112cea587aa4ce4d7ef8753b0cc04775787270b/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs), I've seen this code :

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keySelector));

        return _(); IEnumerable<TSource> _()
        {
            var knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
            foreach (var element in source)
            {
                if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
                    yield return element;
            }
        }
    }
```

I never saw such `return` construction. What does the `_()` means and how to use it ?

As I can't name this block, [I didn't found any reference](https://www.qwant.com/?q=c%23%20_()&t=web).

Comment: I think the formatting/indentation has thrown you off, here. They're returning the result of the method named `_` (badly named). `_` is a local function, which is why it appears inside this method. Local functions were introduced in C# 7 so, relatively, new(ish).

Comment: The code is **exactly** this one. Check the linked page. And it compiles with no problem (VS 2017)

Comment: @himbrombeere: thanks for the duplicate. Its answer is very comprehensive

Comment: It really looks odd. If i'd use local functions i'd declare them before the `return`. And if i'd give them names like `_` and use them only once, i'd ask myself why i use them at all.

Comment: As an aside, if anybody can shed some light on this choice of style - please share. It looks all off to me.

Comment: It's interesting that Jon skeet wrote this unreadable code.

Comment: @SelmanGenç - he didn't. Annotate it, it was not Jon Skeet

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ oh I see, nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a method named `_`, for example:

```
public int _()
{
     //some code here
}
```

Comment: While there *is* a method named `_`, it isn´t publicly available, but just defined locally **within** `DistinctBy`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere well I don't deny it, i can see that there is a locally defined method..., but what would you answer `What does _() means?`? I said that its just a method with a name `_`, although it looks odd or unfamiliar, but its a valid method name.

Comment: understanding that `_` is indeed a variable or function name is part of the answer. That is is meant to mean 'so unimportant that it doesn't deserve a meaningful name' is another part..And understanding local functions should wrap it all up.,